# Название соуса демиглас

Tags: грамотная-речь

как правильно поставить ударение в произношении названия соуса -демиглас?

Answer (score 1):

http://ru.forvo.com/word/demi-glace/

я слышала и как демиглЯсс- ударение тоже на последнем слоге